# Two Threads Executing Same Method

Tags: java, multithreading

I am developing an API request and I'm using multi threading.In the output I'm getting the same request twice generated by two threads.As I debugged two thread are calling the same method again.So need help so that this issue is resolved
This is my pseudo code

```
public void run() {
    logger.debug("Thread " + currentThread().getName() + " Running");
    String message = "";

    Connection connection = null;

    InputStream fileinput = null;
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    try {
        File file = new File("/home/sridhar.anirudh/eclipse-workspace/API/Change.properties");
        fileinput = new FileInputStream(file);
        properties.load(fileinput);
        soapEndpointUrl = properties.getProperty("endpoint_url");
        soapAction = properties.getProperty("soap_action");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        connection = Database.getInstance().getConnection();
    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        logger.error("Failed To Get Connection " + e1.getMessage());
        return;
    }

    if (CATEGORY.equalsIgnoreCase("fraudrestriction")) {
        String soapResponse = callSoapWebServiceFraudRestriction(soapEndpointUrl, soapAction);
        String response_status = "";

        if (soapResponse.contains("<tns:Description>SUCCESS</tns:Description>") &&
            soapResponse.contains("<tns:Code>ERR_000</tns:Code>")) {
            response_status = "SUCCESS";
```

Comment: For sure, if two threads enter that function, they both executes the code... Please provide a real question, and a [mcve], not a "pseudo code" which is not useful as it is a truncated code, not pseudo.

Comment: Hi Jean,How can i make it restricted so that only one thread enters the function

Comment: There's no one answer to "how...so that only one thread enters the function". It depends on (1) what "only one thread enters the function" means (One at a time? One Ever? *Once* ever?), and (2) what a second call should do (Wait? Skip? Fail?). And that's disregarding the question of whether threading is even worth the trouble for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

If you kick off two copies of the thread, they will both run, creating the effect you see.

You can create multiple worker threads, but you need to allocate the work between those workers such that each performs a subset of the total workload.

Since you're (seemingly) parsing and processing a file, and making a network service request in response to that file's contents, it's not clear how you intend to divide up the work. That's the key; to use multiple threads to improve throughput, *you the programmer* must devise a means of partitioning the work between those threads.

As an analogy, if you have one (human) worker working on a job, simply hiring a second worker won't get the job completed any faster unless the work is divided between those workers. That division is your problem. There's nothing magical about threads that can do this for you.